# How to add group using RESTFUL interface in Crowd

Tags: rest, atlassian-crowd

How to add group in Crowd using RESTFUL interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Add a group to a directory](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/REST+Resources#RESTResources-grouplist) in the [REST API documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/Crowd+REST+APIs) of Crowd.

Comment: But to Add user into Group !?